# Problemas com passagem de valores asp.net C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou com um problema, quando vou atribuir o retorno da `query` pra uma variavel do tipo `object` ela passa como `null`.
Tenho outros métodos idênticos e funcionam direito, só esse que não está passando o valor certo.
Consegui ver que o `DbValue` pega o valor certo, mas na hora de atribuir passa nulo.
Meu código está assim:

```
public string getEmailUsuario(string loginRede)
        {
            object email = "";
            string Sql;

             Sql = "SELECT EMAIL FROM VIEW_ADUSERS_LAZ_BR WHERE LOGIN_REDE = @LOGIN";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnIntranet"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGIN", loginRede);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                email = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); <--- Aqui dá o erro. Passa "null"

                if (email != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    return email.ToString();
                }

                return "Sem email";

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _MSGERROR = e.Message.ToString();
                return "Sem email";
            }
            finally { conn.Close(); }
        }
```

Comment: Faz a query no Banco e veja se retornou algum valor. Bem provável que não.

Comment: Já fiz @Marconi e retorna de boa ..

Comment: seu campo LOGIN_REDE  é varchar?

Comment: É uma consulta numa View, está como NVarchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deduzindo que sua coluna `LOGIN_REDE` é varchar você deve incluir as aspas em `@LOGIN` para fazer a comparação entre varchars.

Quando você for trafegar a Query para o banco ela irá ser executada assim:

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM VIEW_ADUSERS_LAZ_BR WHERE LOGIN_REDE = seulogin
```

Em vez de:

```
"SELECT EMAIL FROM VIEW_ADUSERS_LAZ_BR WHERE LOGIN_REDE = @LOGIN"
```

Use:

```
"SELECT EMAIL FROM VIEW_ADUSERS_LAZ_BR WHERE LOGIN_REDE = '@LOGIN'"
```

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar aqui, valeeu

Comment: @AndreeH Deu certo?

Comment: não deu certo. eu vi que eu estava passando coisa errada, consertei mas mesmo assim não funciona, agora tá tudo certo e nada ..

Comment: Agora consegui @Marconi, mas agora tá dando pau na hora de enviar o e-mail.

Comment: @AndreeH abra outra pergunta com a discussão da mesma.

Comment: eu abri. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67426/problema-ao-enviar-e-mail-usando-smtpclient-c/67427#67427