# Problema ao enviar e-mail usando SmtpClient C#

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema na hora de enviar o email, quando executo:

```
objClientSmtp.Send(mensagem_email)
```

No botão **+**, "Non-public members", lá mostra a propriedade `ClientSmtp.ServerSupportsEai` com uma exception: *"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto".*

Onde defino esse objeto ?

Alguém sabe uma solução ?

Meu código está assim:

```
 string emailBody = "";
                string SmtpHost, SmtpPort, SmtpUser, SmtpPass, SmtpEmail;

                SmtpHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_Host"].ToString();
                SmtpPort = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_Port"].ToString();
                SmtpUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_User"].ToString();
                SmtpPass = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_Password"].ToString();
                SmtpEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_Email"].ToString();


                PrjBureauVeritasIntranet.Classes.ClsLogin login = new PrjBureauVeritasIntranet.Classes.ClsLogin();
                login.USUARIO = usuario;

                PrjBureauVeritasIntranet.Classes.ClsSalas reserva = new PrjBureauVeritasIntranet.Classes.ClsSalas();

                if (login.getEmailUsuario(usuario) != "Sem email")
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient ClienteSmtp = new SmtpClient();

                    ClienteSmtp.Host = SmtpHost;
                    ClienteSmtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(SmtpPort);
                    ClienteSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUser, SmtpPass);

                    if (Request.QueryString["ssl"] != null)
                    {
                        ClienteSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    }

                    email.To.Add(login.getEmailUsuario(usuario));
                    email.From = new MailAddress(SmtpEmail);

                    email.Subject = "Confirmação de Reserva de Sala";
                    email.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    emailBody = login.getNomeUsuario(usuario);
                    emailBody += reserva.getMsgUltimaSalaReservada(usuario);

                    email.Body = emailBody;
                    ClienteSmtp.Send(email);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

em que parte do seu código você instanciou este objeto?

tente isso:

```
var objClientSmtp = new SmtpClient(_host, _port); // sendo o host e a port que você vai usar

objClientSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

objClientSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _pass); // sendo user e pass suas credenciais

objClientSmtp.EnableSsl = true;

var mensagem_email = new MailMessage(_sender, _recipient, _subject, _body){ IsBodyHtml = true }; // sendo email que vai enviar, o que vai receber, o assunto, e o email em HTML
```

depois disso você envia:

```
objClientSmtp.Send(mensagem_email);
```